# Dynamic sql for the below query

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

Can someone help me to convert the below query to dynamic sql.

I need to place the below query in a PL/SQL procedure.

Relation to find customers with Inactive Bacs

```
CREATE TABLE INACTIVE_CUS_ID AS
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT
CUST.CUSTOMER_ID ,
case when sum(case when NVL(BAC.ACCOUNT_STATUS,'A')='I' then 0 else 1 end ) >0 then 'Y'
else 'N' end CUS_HAVE_LIVE_BAC_FLG ,
max(to_date(SUBSTR(NVL(BAC.UPDATE_TS,SYSDATE),1,10),'YYYY-MM-DD')) as LAST_BAC_CEASE_DATE
FROM
OPS$QDW.PSO_CUSTOMER CUST ,
OPS$QDW.PSO_CUST_BLNG_ACCT BAC    
where CUST.CUSTOMER_ID = BAC.CUSTOMER_ID GROUP BY CUST.CUSTOMER_ID)
where CUS_HAVE_LIVE_BAC_FLG ='N'
AND LAST_BAC_CEASE_DATE < SYSDATE -730;
```

Comment: Why would you want to build a table with a static data set rather than a view or just executing a query?

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned why do you want to run  the create table in the procedure rather than use a SQL statement directly. May be you want to pass arguments to your procedure and use variables in your DDL?

We can't directly run DDLs in a procedure. You may use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` for such purposes.

In the below example the procedure has both arguments for Table names and some other values to be used in the select statement.

Bind arguments may be used for values ( with the `USING` keyword) , but only variable concatenation could be used for dynamic table names and column names.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE yourprocedure (p_table_name    VARCHAR2,
                                           p_arg1          VARCHAR2,
                                           p_arg2          NUMBER)
AS
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
         'Create table yourtablename as select col1,col2 from '
      || othertable
      || '  where somothercol1 = :x AND somothercol2 = :y'
      USING p_arg1, p_arg2;
END;
/
```